# IOS storyboard uiview and uiscrollview position

Tags: ios, uiview, position, storyboard, iboutlet

I created a `UIViewController` in the `storyboard` , the hierarchy is as follows :

--`UIView`

---`UIView` (`IBOutlet` -> scrollContentView)

----`UILabel`

----`UILabel`

....

In class function `viewDidLoad`:

```
[_scrollContentView removeFromSuperview];

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

[scrollView addSubview:_scrollContentView];
[scrollView setContentSize:_scrollContentView.size];
[scrollView setDelegate:self];
```

Run it, coordinates of the starting point in the middle of the display screen the _scrollContentView.

print the `_scrollContentView` point is (0,0), Why it's position is wrong?

I test add a new `UILabel` to scrollView, the label's point is (0,0), but it's not `IBOutlet`, It's display is normal.

Comment: Can you post screen shot or elaborate your question?

Comment: Why don't you add `UIScrollView` in `storyboard` itself?